# Android - how to make an Activity that extends a ListView also extend my BaseView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a BaseActivity which has my header:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
        @Override
        public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
            super.setContentView(layoutResID);      
        {
            Button home_header = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_header);
            Button questions_header = (Button)findViewById(R.id.questions_header);

            home_header.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
            {  
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {                   
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent( BaseActivity.this , ProblemioActivity.class);
                  BaseActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });                 

            questions_header.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
            {  
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {                   
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent( BaseActivity.this , MyQuestionsActivity.class);
                  BaseActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });         
        }
    }
}
```

It works when I extend it like this:

```
public class ProblemActivity extends BaseActivity
```

but if I have a class which extends a ListActivity, I can not also extend the BaseActivity.  Is there a way for me to force the classes that extend ListActivity to also be able to have the header?  Right now I make them have the header by extending the BaseActivity, but since some extend ListActivity already, I can't seem to do it that way.

How can I get around this and make the classes that extend the ListActivity also be able to have the header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `BaseActivity` extend from `ListActivity`, but this will make all your activities a `ListActivity` and probably will create problems to other activities that aren't a ListActivity.

`ListActivity` isn't required to use `ListView`. You can use `ListView` in plain activities. If you want to continue using a BaseActivity for all your activities, then don't use ListActivity and manage ListView by yourself. Another alternative would be to make your own `ListActivity` that extends from `BaseActivity`. Here's a basic example of this:

```
class MyBaseListActivity extends BaseActivity {

  protected ListView getListView() {
    return (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  }

  protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
    return getListView().getAdapter();
  }

  ...


}
```

Comment: would it be simpler to just make a BaseListActivity and extend that with the Activities which have the lists?